# PHP/JavaScript Adding new options

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is it possible somehow to copy option attributes when moving item from one select-list to other select-list. This is my `JavaScript` which adds item to other list:

```
function addUser(form) {
    var fl = form.resources.length -1;
    var au = form.assigned.length -1;
    //gets value of percentage assignment of selected resource
    var perc = form.percentage_assignment.options[form.percentage_assignment.selectedIndex].value;

    var users = "x";

    //build array of assiged users
    for (au; au > -1; au--) {
        users = users + "," + form.assigned.options[au].value + ","
    }

    //Pull selected resources and add them to list
    for (fl; fl > -1; fl--) {
        if (form.resources.options[fl].selected && users.indexOf("," + form.resources.options[fl].value + ",") == -1) {
            t = form.assigned.length
            opt = new Option(form.resources.options[fl].text+" ["+perc+"%]", form.resources.options[fl].value);
            form.hperc_assign.value += form.resources.options[fl].value+"="+perc+";";
            form.assigned.options[t] = opt
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is that when it adds the item to other `selectlist` it has no attributes.
Here is for example:

List 1

```
<option style="color:''" value="''">Option1</option>
```

And when I put that item from list 1 to list 2:

```
<option>Option1</option>
```

So I repeat question, is it possible somehow to copy or to move item with his attributes?

***And the second question is maby someone know's what am i doing wrong here coz i get error, what should i delete or add to fix it??***

```
$titleBlock->addCell('<select class="text" size="1" name="user_id">
                    <?php
                        $sql = "SELECT user_id, user_color FROM dotp_users";
                        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                        $new = array();
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            $new[$row['user_id']] = $row['user_color'];
                        }
                        foreach ($user_list as $key=>$value){
                                    echo '<option style="color:'.$new[$key].'" value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>', '',
                     '<form action="?m=tasks" method="post" name="userIdForm">','</form>');
```

Answer (score 0):

About the php code, you should not name a variable 'new' since that is a reserved php word (to create objects). That might be causing the error